# Racket Boggle Game

Tags: racket, boggle

I am working on a big boggle game in racket for a class. I am still trying to figure out racket so I am really struggling with this. I am supposed to print out a 5x5 board with random letters in it and then I need to print out a list of lists with the characters from the board for my instructor to use in his player. However when I call the instructors-player it is generating a new list of characters. Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Creating my lists:

```
(define alphabet (list  "B " "C " "D " "F " "G " "H " "J " "K " "L " "M " "N" "P " "R " "S " "T " "V " "W " "X " "Y " "Z "))
(define vowel (list "A " "E " "I " "O " "U "))

(define (pick-item alphabet)(list-ref alphabet (random(length alphabet))));;select element randomly from alphabet list
(define (pick-vowel vowel)(list-ref vowel (random(length vowel)))) ;;select element randomly from vowel list

(define (make-row alphabet) (list (pick-item alphabet)(pick-vowel vowel)(pick-item alphabet)(pick-vowel vowel)(pick-item alphabet))) ;;make a list of vowels and consonants

(define (make-board) (list (make-row alphabet) (make-row alphabet) (make-row alphabet) (make-row alphabet) (make-row alphabet))) ;;make a list of 5 lists for board

(define (instructors-player gameGrid) (make-board) )
```

Drawing the board and calling the instructors-player

```
(define gameGrid(draw-board (make-board)))
(instructors-player gameGrid);;call for instructors input
```

[image: Racket output when I run]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(define a-board (make-board))      ; make a board
(draw-board a-board)               ; draw the board
(instructors-player a-board)       ; give a-board to the instructor's player
```

Maybe the last line needs to be:

```
(draw-board (instructors-player a-board))
```

Comment: If I do that I get two different lists without the grid I need.  I tried this instead, but get an error message:                                                                                                `(define a-board(make-board))``(define gameGrid(draw-board(a-board)))``(instructors-player a-board)`

Comment: I am still getting a list that doesn't make what is in my board. When I tried what I just posted I get this error: Error: application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '(("P " "E " "T " "E " "G ") ("M " "U " "V " "I " "X ") ("K " "U " "D " "O " "M ") ("G " "U " "W " "A " "N ") ("W " "E " "N " "I " "M "))

Comment: What is the documentation of `instructors-board` ?

Comment: What do you mean by documentation?

Comment: You wrote: "for my instructor to use in his player." What kind of value do his player expect to get from you?

Comment: It expects a list of 5 lists. So the output I am getting is correct, but what prints in my game board does not match what prints in my list. It generates a second list of lists.